# JavaFX treeview state incorrect

Tags: javafx, treeview, observablelist

I have a situation where the state of the JavaFX `TreeView` is not correct when the items are added to the root one by one which can be recreated with the code below.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>();
        TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("Root");
        treeView.setRoot(root);
        treeView.setShowRoot(false);
        
        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>("Foo"));
        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>("Bar"));
        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>("Baz"));

        var scene = new Scene(new StackPane(treeView), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

[image: JavaFX TreeView bug]

As you can see the second item has a blue rectangle around it (I think this means the item is focused). Using `treeView.refresh()` or `treeView.getFocusModel()` does not seem to clear this up however as soon as I interact with the TreeView using the keyboard and mouse everything is corrected.

If I change the code above to replace the three calls to `add` with `addAll` then nothing is selected or focused when the window opens.

I have noticed that if the **root** node is added to the `TreeView` **after** all the items have been added to it then the state of the tree view is consistent when using `add` or `addAll`; In these cases the **first** item in the `TreeView` is surrounded by a blue rectangle.

Can anyone explain the difference in behaviour? Is this a bug?

This was tested using version 15.0.1 of the JDK and JavaFX.

Comment: sounds like a bug - please file an issue so we don't forget to tackle it :)

Comment: btw: no regression - quick check against fx8, 11, 15: all misbehaving

Comment: @kleopatra are you able to file an issue? I don't have an account to add issues to the openJDK bug tracker.

Comment: here it is: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8256142 - thanks for the question and the example :)